# posicion de matriz undefined lanza error

Tags: javascript, array, clase

tengo un problema con un método que hice en una de mis clases, el problema es el siguiente:

Mi metodo nextNeighbor recibe una matriz llena de instancias de mi clase. Cada instancia contiene su posicion(x, y) en la matriz. a la hora de que lo llamo me busca las cells vecinas en la matriz  de la cell que llamo al metodo, si una de estas no existe, yo esperaba que simplemente se pusiera en el arreglo como undefined, pero este me lanza el error ***Uncaught TypeError: matrix[(this.y + 1)] is undefined***. Lo raro es que solo me sucede con las ultimas 2, las cuales busco en la posicion Y, si alguna de las 2 primeras que es cuando busco en x no existe me las pone como undefined y las puedo procesar pero si esto sucede en las que busco en Y salta el error, alguna alternativa que pueda usar o solucion?

```js
export default class Cell {

    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.visited = false;

        this.walls = {
            left: true,
            right: true,
            top: true,
            bot: true
        }

    }
    
    nextNeighbor(matrix) {
            console.log(matrix);
            console.log(this.x, this.y);

            let arrNeighbors = [ ['left', matrix[this.y][this.x - 1] ], 
            ['right', matrix[this.y][this.x + 1] ], 
            ['top', matrix[this.y - 1][this.x] ], 
            ['bot', matrix[this.y + 1][this.x] ]];

            let unvisited = arrNeighbors.filter(n => n[1] != undefined && !n[1].visited);  

            return unvisited.length == 0 ? null : unvisited[Math.round(Math.random(1)*(unvisited.length-1))];
    }
}
```

Comment: Imagina que `matrix` es una matriz de 2x2 y las coords de la celda son `x=0,y=0`, cuando quieras buscar si existe un vecino en las coords `x -1`, dicha posición no existe... lo mismo para `y -1`. El problema es que no estas validando si la coord esta **"fuera de los bordes"**

Comment: si asi es, y tengo entendido que si estuviera fuera de los bordes me daría un valor undefined y con el filter lo eliminaria, no es asi?. Eso me sucede cuando uno de los vecinos x esta fuera de los bordes, si esta fuera de estos el filter lo elimina, pero cuando una de las y esta fuera de los bordes me lanza el error mencionado.

Comment: El problema esta cuando creas el arreglo `arrNeighbors`, ahí no estas validando la dimensión de la matriz, como para saber si van a existir las coords. Por ejemplo `matrix[this.y - 1][this.x]` en el caso que te comente anteriormente te va a dar error ya que`matrix[this.y - 1] == undefined`  y por lo tanto `undefined[this.x]` explota!

Comment: ohh okay lo entiendo, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarme entonces tendria que cambiar eso de las y para por lo menos validar eso, veré como lo cambio gracias. En un rato mas pongo la respuesta.